# Combining Excel Formulas That Work Separately But Not Together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've managed to give myself a headache in Excel. I've made 2 separate formulas that work separately but can't figure out how to combine them. Separate formulas are:

```
IF($N$19=" "," ",IF(AND($N$19>=(--"5:00 AM"),$N$19<(--"5:30 AM"),$O$8="Optimized"),"Meal 4", IF($O$8="Traditional"," ", IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 4"),"Meal 3",IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 3"),"Meal 2", IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 2"),"Meal 1",
```

and

```
IF(NOT(OR($O$8="Traditional",$O$8="Optimized",$O$8="5/2")), IF(AND($T$6=5, $U$6="AM"), "Meal 1", IF(AND($T$8=5, $U$8="AM"),"Meal 2", IF(AND($T$10=5, $U$10="AM"), "Meal 3", IF(AND($T$12=5, $U$12="AM"), "Meal 4", " ")))))
```

When I put them together as below I get a #VALUE error:

```
=IF($N$19=" "," ",IF(AND($N$19>=(--"5:00 AM"),$N$19<(--"5:30 AM"),$O$8="Optimized"),"Meal 4", IF($O$8="Traditional"," ", IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 4"),"Meal 3",IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 3"),"Meal 2", IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 2"),"Meal 1", IF(NOT(OR($O$8="Traditional",$O$8="Optimized",$O$8="5/2")), IF(AND($T$6=5, $U$6="AM"), "Meal 1", IF(AND($T$8=5, $U$8="AM"),"Meal 2", IF(AND($T$10=5, $U$10="AM"), "Meal 3", IF(AND($T$12=5, $U$12="AM"), "Meal 4", " ")))))))))))
```

To my mind, if the conditions of the first part of the formula are not met, then the second portion of the formula should take effect and function just as it does on its own. This is not the case, I think the conditions interfere with each other somehow but I'm rather new and dumb so I can't figure it out.

Would be grateful for any input!

Answer (score 1):

The logic of nested ifs shows that something may be missing in the `**MISS**` spot.

```
=IF($N$19=" "," ",
   IF(AND($N$19>=(--"5:00 AM"),$N$19<(--"5:30 AM"),$O$8="Optimized"),"Meal 4", 
     IF($O$8="Traditional"," ", 
       IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 4"),"Meal 3",
         IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 3"),"Meal 2", 
           IF(AND($O$8="Optimized",C11="Meal 2"),"Meal 1", 
             IF(NOT(OR($O$8="Traditional",$O$8="Optimized",$O$8="5/2")), **MISS**,
               IF(AND($T$6=5, $U$6="AM"), "Meal 1", 
                 IF(AND($T$8=5, $U$8="AM"),"Meal 2", 
                   IF(AND($T$10=5, $U$10="AM"), "Meal 3", 
                     IF(AND($T$12=5, $U$12="AM"), "Meal 4", " ")
                   )
                 )
               )
             )
           )
         )
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

Can you please confirm that this is the intended logic?